# How to encrypt something with a key?

Tags: encryption, diffie-hellman, decryption, instant-messaging

I read a lot about security on the internet, especially how services like telegram work with their encryption and how they do it. I also heard of the Diffie-Hellman Key Exchange, which was quite difficult to understand, but now I get the point.

My question is: lets say I implemented this whole stuff and I have some keys. How do I actually encrypt something with these keys? Are there any Pre-made functions in some languages? I literally have no idea how I can encrypt something when I have both parts that I need, the payload to encrypt and a key or some sort of encryption key. Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are libraries for most programming languages. For example, for PHP see: http://php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.examples.php for some examples.

I would also recommend that you start out with basic, symmetric encryption (both sides have the same, 'pre-shared' key), before starting on the complicated stuff with private/public key pairs.